# iOS drawing on iPad is slow but iPhone is perfect

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, drawing, paint

Can anyone see something in this code that allows it to work butter soft on iPhone, but slow and spotty/chunky on iPad both retina and non? Any ideas of how to speed it up for the iPad? I just want it to finger paint basically, with control over brush size,opacity and edge (thats why I have the gradient, for soft edges)

Thank you

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPointTemp = [touch locationInView:parentView.view];
    CGPoint currentPoint = CGPointMake((currentPointTemp.x /imageScale)+ (posOffset.x/imageScale), (currentPointTemp.y /imageScale) + (posOffset.y/imageScale));
    currentPoint.y -= 10;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height), NO, 0); 

    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetAlpha(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), opacity);
    CGContextBeginPath (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextAddArc(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, glamzyDelegate.brushSize, 0, 6.28318531, 0);
    CGContextClosePath (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()); 
    CGContextClip(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    CGPoint myStartPoint, myEndPoint;
    CGFloat myStartRadius, myEndRadius;
    myStartPoint.x = lastPoint.x;
    myStartPoint.y =  lastPoint.y;
    myEndPoint.x = lastPoint.x;
    myEndPoint.y =  lastPoint.y;
    myStartRadius = 0;
    myEndRadius = glamzyDelegate.brushSize;

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), gradient, myStartPoint, myStartRadius, myEndPoint, myEndRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting problem. I'd love to know what's going wrong. Have you tested it on the device? Or were your observations based on the performance in simulator?

Comment: Well thats the interesting thing. On the iPad simulator, its smooth too. iPad & iPhone simulator smooth, iPhone device, iPod touch, smooth too. iPad device, not so hot, spotty and slow. If you are really interested, you can download the app. this code is running in Glamzy, which has a free version for both iPhone and iPad. I thought it could be a retina issue, but heard report of this on iPad 2 (I only have the retina iPad) It may come down to a better way to do a gradient or soft edge brush. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

Never call any drawing routines in the touch event.

1. You should override the drawrect method of the view
2. Call setneedsdisplay in the touch event

Comment: That's just pushing it from one side of the plate to another--whether you're drawing in touchesMoved or drawRect, the code's running on the main thread blocking user interaction. I might be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you won't see any difference in performance using drawRect instead.

Comment: Could be, but what about the graphics context? The documentation has this to say:

"Prior to calling its drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto the stack, making it current. If you are not using a UIView object to do your drawing, however, you must push a valid context onto the stack manually using the UIGraphicsPushContext function."

Comment: There is no noticeable improvements by putting the draw code in drawRect. I'll leave it there because it seems like an agreed upon standard. Any other ideas on how to speed it up on iPad? Does anyone know a better way to draw a soft edge, it could be that the gradient is too expensive. (will test non gradient drawing soon)